# Is there a way to make the total time spent on the activities to always be 24hrs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to randomly generate the Number of hours someone spends doing various activities daily.

I have created an object that will store the object key (activities), its values(hours) and an array to store hold them. i also used a random method to generate the number of hours and make sure it that each initial value doesn't surpass 24hrs before randomly generating the next object property. but I need the number of hours to always sum up to 24hrs.

```
 let organised = new Object(),
    pworks = null,
    commutes = null,
    fun = null,
    work = false;
    let arr= [];
   if(!work){ 
       organised.pworks = Math.floor(Math.random()*24)
       if(organised.pworks < 24){
           console.log('you spend ' + organised.pworks+'hrs' + ' on Primary Work' )
          arr.push(organised.pworks)
          organised.commutes = Math.floor(Math.random()*24)
          if(organised.commutes + organised.pworks < 24){
            arr.push(organised.commutes)
            console.log('you spend ' + organised.commutes+'hrs' + ' on Commute' )
            organised.fun = Math.floor(Math.random()*24)
            if(organised.commutes + organised.pworks + organised.fun <= 24){
            console.log('you spend ' + organised.fun+'hrs' + ' on having Fun' )
    arr.push(organised.fun)
  }
}
```

}
}

you spend 6hrs on Primary Work
you spend 10hrs on Commute
you spend 8hrs on having Fun

Comment: FWIW, there's almost never any reason to use `new Object`. Just use `{}` instead.

Comment: *"you spend 6hrs on Primary Work you spend 10hrs on Commute you spend 8hrs on having Fun"* If you don't sleep. Unless sleep is a subset of one of those. "Fun" would make the most sense, but you often don't get any fun with the calculation as described... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pick random values that are randomly within the time you have *left*, not the full 24 hours. So for instance, this is incorrect:

```
organised.commutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24);
```

...because it doesn't allow for the time taken by `organized.pworks`. So:

```
organised.commutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * (24 - organized.pworks));
```

...and so on for the next one, which has to allow for both `organized.pworks` and `organized.commute`. It may be handy to keep a running tally so you don't have to keep adding in further properties:

```
var remaining = 24;
organised.pworks = Math.floor(Math.random() * remaining);
remaining -= organised.pworks;
// ...
organised.commutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * remaining);
remaining -= organised.commutes;
// ...
```

Then you probably don't want a random value for the last one, you just want the time remaining:

```
organised.fun = remaining;
```